# Django filtering on foreign key

Tags: django, filtering

Hi and thanks for reading.

Below is the relevant piece of my Data Model.  I want to pull all the threads for a given section in my forum.  but I'm struggling to get this to work.  Here's the data model:

```
class ForumSections(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Section: %s" % (self.heading)

class ForumThread(models.Model):
    heading = models.ForeignKey(ForumSections, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    threadTitle = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    threadStatus = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Thread: %s Under Section: %s" % (self.threadTitle, self.heading
```

so I'm thinking I want to do something like:

```
ForumThread.objects.filter(ForumSections__heading=heading)
```

However this returns an error :

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'ForumSections' into field
```

Really appreciate your help - I'm stuck here.

Thanks!
Tommy

Comment: You are stuck here, but what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

```
ForumThread.objects.filter(heading__heading=heading)
```

as *heading* is the field in the model *ForumThread*.

Comment: Hey thanks - this works.  For some reason I thought I had to reference the table in a backward foreign key.